# SecurityException: Request failed. - Entity Framework Code First (Sql Compact 4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, ef-code-first, security, sql-server-ce-4

1. I created an **assembly (dll)** with the following classes:

**Person.cs**

```
[Table("People")]
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

**DataContext.cs**

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    public DataContext()
        : base("name=DataConnection")
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Calc.cs**

```
public class Calc
{
    public int Sum(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
}
```

Using Nuget installed the following package:

> Install-Package EFCodeFirst.SqlServerCompact

2. I created a new **site MVC 3**

I added the dll reference to previously created

I modified the following actions on `HomeController`

**HomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Sample Security Error";
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Sum(int num1, int num2)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Sample Security Error";
    return View("Index", num1 + num2);
}
```

Added a new controller

**PeopleController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var db = new DataContext())
    {
        var people = from p in db.People
                        select p;

        return View(people.ToList());
    }
}
```

I changed the `View/Home` with the following code:

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model int?
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
@Html.ActionLink("Sum", "Sum", new { num1 = 2, num2 = 4})
@if (Model.HasValue)
{ 
    <p>The value is: @Model.Value</p>
}
else
{ 
    <p>No value</p>
}
```

New `View/People`

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Error.SecurityException.Model.Person>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "People";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>@item.Name</li>
}
</ul>
```

**In Web.config I added the connection string**

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DataConnection" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Data.sdf;" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
</connectionStrings>
```

`App_Data` folder created the database `Data.sdf` with the same structure as the `Person.cs` class.

Using Nuget installed the following package:

> Install-Package EFCodeFirst.SqlServerCompact

**Result**

The code in local IIS worked perfectly!

**Sum values**

[image: Sum value]

**Display persons**

[image: Dados do Data.sdf]

**Error**

When I published the site, while trying to display the persons, a security error message is displayed;

> System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.

The sum values is normally done!

I published the project [this](http://teste.sextaigreja.com.br/) address.

Clicking the `People` menu you can see the error!

Compact the sample project and published at [this address](http://teste.sextaigreja.com.br/Error.SecurityExeption.rar).

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Do you have write permissions on the sdf file?

Comment: Nobody is going to download a 11MB RAR file to debug your issue. Part of the problem might be that you are using an old CTP and not the release package, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact

Comment: Version 0.8 (updated via Nuget) see image: http://i1118.photobucket.com/albums/k610/ridermansb/Nuget.png   I removed the packages and dlls of the project. Follow the link for download:  http://teste.sextaigreja.com.br/Error.SecurityExeption-min.rar   I have both the permission and the file folder Data.sdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was fixed in version 4.1 of the Entity Framework!
It was a bug of their entity framework CF

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't open your solution because it's configured to run in IIS... Can you add;

```
<trust level="Medium"/>
```

In your local projects web.config (under system.web) and run it locally? Do you get the same error? If you do, its a partial trust issue!

Matt

Comment: Locally it works perfectly!
Changed to `<trust level="Medium"/>` and error remained. The funny thing is that the error happens only on this host. Host the site on another host and it worked perfectly. But I had to add the line of code `<trust level="Medium"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I got here looking for a Security Exception that was being fired in my own ASP.Net MVC application. Although my problem might not be exactly the same (it was raising a System.Configuration.ConfigurationPermission when running any page that called DbContext) I found a straightforward solution that could be suitable for many cases. I changed my web.config, adding a requirePermission="false" in the custom section, as follows:

```
  <configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

Hope this helps somebody with the same problem.